# parse a text file suing regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Hi I have a text file that I need to parse

```
libA/cellA/view1/data.dm#1 - edit default 
libA/cellA/view1/master.tag#1 - edit defau
libA/cellA/view1/sch.oa#1 - edit default c
libA/cellA/view1/thumbnail_128x128.png#1 -
libA/cellB/view1/data.dm#1 - edit default 
libA/cellB/view1/master.tag#1 - edit defau
libA/cellB/view1/sch.oa#1 - edit default c
libA/cellB/view1/thumbnail_128x128.png#1 -
libA/cellB/symbol/master.tag#1 - edit defa
libA/cellB/symbol/symbol.oa#1 - edit defau
libA/cellB/symbol/thumbnail_128x128.png#1 
libA/cellC/view1/data.dm#1 - edit default 
libA/cellC/view1/master.tag#1 - edit defau
libA/cellC/view1/sch.oa#1 - edit default c
libA/cellC/view1/thumbnail_128x128.png#1 -
libA/cellD/veriloga/data.dm#1 - edit defau
libA/cellD/veriloga/master.tag#1 - edit de
libA/cellD/veriloga/netlist.oa#1 - edit de
libA/cellD/veriloga/veriloga.va#1 - edit d
libA/cellE/view1/data.dm#1 - edit default 
libA/cellE/view1/master.tag#1 - edit defau
```

Step1:In above text file I only want to keep text until third occurance of '/' character. for example output should be as below:

```
libA/cellA/view1
libA/cellA/view1
libA/cellA/view1
libA/cellA/view1
libA/cellB/view1
libA/cellB/view1
libA/cellB/view1
libA/cellB/view1
libA/cellB/view2
libA/cellB/view2
libA/cellB/view2
libA/cellC/view1
libA/cellC/view1
libA/cellC/view1
libA/cellC/view1
libA/cellD/view3
libA/cellD/view3
libA/cellD/view3
libA/cellD/view3
libA/cellE/view1
libA/cellE/view1
```

Setp2: Then I would like to delete duplicate lines retaining empty line in between:

```
libA/cellA/view1



libA/cellB/view1



libA/cellB/view2


libA/cellC/view1


libA/cellD/view3




libA/cellE/view1
```

any pointer on how to do this in Perl?
I'm trying something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# File: parse.pl

unless (open(MYFILE, "sample.txt")) 
{
    die ("cannot open input file file1\n");
}

unless (open(OUTFILE, ">outfile.txt")) 
{
    die ("cannot open output file outfile\n");
}


# if the program gets this far, the file was
# opened successfully
$line = <MYFILE>;
while ($line ne "") 
{
  #print ($line);

 my ($lib, $cell, $view) = split /:/, $line;
 #print "$lib\n";
 #print "$cell\n";
 #print "$view\n";
 print OUTFILE ($lib/$cell/$view/n);
  $line = <MYFILE>;

}
```

Comment: You want `split` and a hash, not a regular expression. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can't I use regex and substitute nothing after occurrence of third '/' character?

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. It's not just `/`---it's also all the stuff in between the slashes that you want to keep. Also, is your example output even correct? It looks like there are still duplicate lines for `libA/cellC/view1`.

Comment: Since you updated your post with what you've tried so far (I guess... but a single malformed regex match isn't really going to do anything), I'll point out that you probably also need some code to process your input file line by line and make some decisions based on what you find.

Comment: Sorry I update the post to correct example output. Thanks for your help

Comment: I just update main post with the code I'm trying right now, I still have a issue with below print line:print OUTFILE ($lib/$cell/$view/n);

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Save as `script.pl` (or whatever) and invoke like so: `perl script.pl input.txt`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %unique;

while (<>) {
    my @parts = split(/\//, $_);
    my $key = join('/', @parts[0 .. 2]);

    if (!$unique{$key}++) {
        print $key;
    }

    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Could maybe pop parts, so it copes with different path lengths.

Answer (score 0):

It's something like this

**Code:**

```
my %unique = ();
my @fields = undef;
while(<DATA>){
    chomp;
    @fields = split /\//, $_;
    if (not $unique{"$fields[0]/$fields[1]/$fields[2]"}++){
        print "$fields[0]/$fields[1]/$fields[2]"
    }else{
        print "\n";
    }
}
#map {print $_."\n"} keys %unique;

__DATA__
libA/cellA/view1/data.dm#1 - edit default
libA/cellA/view1/master.tag#1 - edit defau
libA/cellA/view1/sch.oa#1 - edit default c
libA/cellA/view1/thumbnail_128x128.png#1 -
libA/cellB/view1/data.dm#1 - edit default
libA/cellB/view1/master.tag#1 - edit defau
libA/cellB/view1/sch.oa#1 - edit default c
libA/cellB/view1/thumbnail_128x128.png#1 -
libA/cellB/symbol/master.tag#1 - edit defa
libA/cellB/symbol/symbol.oa#1 - edit defau
libA/cellB/symbol/thumbnail_128x128.png#1
libA/cellC/view1/data.dm#1 - edit default
libA/cellC/view1/master.tag#1 - edit defau
libA/cellC/view1/sch.oa#1 - edit default c
libA/cellC/view1/thumbnail_128x128.png#1 -
libA/cellD/veriloga/data.dm#1 - edit defau
libA/cellD/veriloga/master.tag#1 - edit de
libA/cellD/veriloga/netlist.oa#1 - edit de
libA/cellD/veriloga/veriloga.va#1 - edit d
libA/cellE/view1/data.dm#1 - edit default
libA/cellE/view1/master.tag#1 - edit defau
```

**Output:**

```
libA/cellA/view1


libA/cellB/view1


libA/cellB/symbol

libA/cellC/view1


libA/cellD/veriloga


libA/cellE/view1
```